# Google maps Geocoder returned values not as expected

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the `Geocoder` to get some lat and lng data.

This is the data I am expecting to get

```
"geometry" : {
     "location" : {
         "lat" : 37.42291810,
         "lng" : -122.08542120
      }....
```

But the data I am actually receiving looks like this:

[image]

It is as if it has been minified.

I am creating a `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();` and then using that to pass in a value like such `geocoder.geocode({address: country},createPin);` where country is an address.

Has anyone encountered this before? Tips on how to get the right results?

Answer (score 1):

The location object has two methods for these purpose:

You can use:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    address:"Some Direction"
}, function(r) { 
    for(i in r){
      var lat = r[i].geometry.location.lat(); 
      var lng = r[i].geometry.location.lng();
      // ...
    }

});
```

Reference: [Google Maps Javascript API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1)

Answer (score 0):

just do:

`.lat()` and `.lng()` on your object.

you will get the results